# cgi module FieldStorage() function not receiving arguments

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am trying to get a Python cgi module to work.
Python file runs well, for example then I try to print out , but once it comes to recive a GET or POST argument the cgi.FieldStorage() function does not receive any input.
The print statement for FieldStorage output:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

You can find all the necessary code below. I have simplified my script to the bare minimum, trying to made it work.
It won't work either via GET nor POST.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()


form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

subMail = form.getfirst("mail")

print form
print subMail
```

The HTML page (nor POST nor GET are working)

```
<form action="cgi-bin/mail.py" method="post" id="frm-landingPage1" class="form">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Indirizzo email" name="mail" id="frm-landingPage1-email" required value="">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Invia" name="_submit" id="frm-landingPage1-submit">
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show the HTML page that is submitting the form.

Comment: Please post the entire page, not just the bare form.

Comment: As requested, http://pastebin.com/GHnSgiHP

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on the html page.  Are you sure that the correct CGI script is being called?  Can you add a silly print statement (something like "hello Fred") and see if that shows up in the script output, just to verify that the server is executing the correct script?

Comment: Yep, the server executes the right script... Could it be something related with my Plesk-Apache config?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all pre-settings proper like CGI Environment and make sure the CGI Script is in correct path. Please read this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

Comment: The server uses Plesk, test scripts generated by the panel works just fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a misconfiguration issue, could you expand your answer? What I should check? (the script is in the right path)